# Making API Calls, from VueJS App with Axios (Using Headers)

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I've been learning both Angular2 and VueJS just to see which I prefer, I can safely say I prefer VueJS just with its ease of use, its great documentation, its speed etc

I'm trying to do some API calls using Axios in Vue. These were going perfectly when using the JSON placeholder data from:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

I'm now trying to do more 'real world' example, the call I'm trying to do requires headers to be sent with the request.

I tried to add these, but of course how I've currently been calling them is from the Client Side part of the app (CORS blocks this).

With Angular2 I ran my app alongside Express, from Express I ran the calls which then passed the data to the view.

How would I best achieve the same result with Vue?

Edit: I've done some research and found NUXT.JS which seems to be SSR? However, I'm unsure how Nuxt helps me in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: is `CORS`  allowed in the server ?

Comment: I think the problem may be, that I'm not actually using a server? As my understanding goes anyway. VueJS is solely the view layer, so I'm wondering how I actually go about doing stuff like this with Vue

Comment: I believe I do yes, which is why I'm asking how I go about this? The API I use requires headers. Which in my Angular2 test project was solved using Express. I guess my question is what is the alternative for Vue? I see there is a GitHub template which has Express integrated. But doing some research people recommend avoiding it?